# How to get derivatives from current versions of all files in a folder

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-data-management

I am trying to load the current version of all IFC files that are stored in a given folder in BIM 360 Docs into the Forge Model Viewer.

To get the derivatives of each IFC file I am calling

```
projects/:project_id/folders/:folder_id/contents?filter[hidden]=false
```

In the included property of this response I get

- Items of type items:autodesk.bim360:Document that seems to be the current version, but they have no derivatives.
- Items of type items:autodesk.bim360:File that have a derivatives, but come from files that have been moved or deleted.

If I would filter out this call to return only Documents like

```
projects/:project_id/folders/:folder_id/contents?filter[extension.type]=items:autodesk.bim360:Document
```

Then the data property seems to return all current versions of the files in that folder that I am looking for, but again it has no derivatives.

How do I get derivatives from an items:autodesk.bim360:Document type or is there another way to achieve what I'm trying to do here?

I also don't really understand the difference between the type items:autodesk.bim360:Document and items:autodesk.bim360:File, but it looks that I need the items:autodesk.bim360:Document. If anyone could explain the difference between these, that would be helpfull as well.

Answer (score 0):

**Plans** folder on BIM 360 shows the extracted views, which are identified as `bim360:Document`, while the original file is identified as `bim360:File`. When navigating on this folder, you need to correlate the extracted views (`Documents`) with the file where it comes from. [This blog article](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/show-list-bim-360-docs-plans-folder) described how it could be done in .NET.

**Project Files** folder will show only files, which is what you see on the BIM 360 interface.

As you're talking about IFC files, then you need to post a [translation job](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/job-POST/) to the original file (`Files`) and access its derivatives. In this perspective, ignore the extracted views (`Documents`).

Comment: Based on the article, I've filtered the folder contents call to obtain only the visibleTypes from this folder. I don't think I should do a translation job as the IFC files are uploaded to BIM 360 docs and processed automatically which would create a derivative, right? What I do next is a GET projects/:project_id/items/:item_id/refs for each version I got in the included and filter this by bim360:File. This seems to give me the items I need and contain the derivatives in the relationships property.

Comment: Correct, you don't need to extract files on BIM 360, unless you want an additional translation (e.g. we automatically extract viewables, if you want RVT to IFC, you need to post that job)

Comment: A GET /projects/:project_id/versions/:version_id/refs on a bim360:Document does not return a versions:autodesk.bim360:File for documents that have been copied/moved into a folder. So I can still not get the derivatives from documents that have been copied/moved. How can I get derivatives for these?

Comment: there are no derivatives from a `bim360:Document`, this is already the derivative, in this case the extracted view

Comment: But that's the whole point, the 'bim360:Document' that I get from a 'GET projects/:project_id/folders/:folder_id/contents' don't contain a derivatives in the relationships. How to get the derivatives from a 'bim360:Document'?